# Maior precisão em problema de distancia entre dois pontos

Tags: c

Estou tentando resolver um problema de árvore geradora mínima, onde tento encontrar o caminho mínimo para ligar todos nós. Os nós representam objetos com posição definida por x, y (números inteiros) no espaço, portanto eu encontro a distância entre um e outro através do seguinte trecho:

```
dist  = sqrt(pow(x2 - x1, 2) + pow(y2 - y1, 2))
```

Como citei acima, `x` e `y` são números inteiros e o resultado final deve ser um `double` com a soma do caminho que percorre a menor distancia para juntar todos nós.

O que está ocorrendo é que meus resultados estão sempre dando valores semelhantes, porém, não exatos ao que o sistema exige e minha resposta não é aceita.

Ex:

> saida programa: 98.00 saida esperada: 98.02

Como posso melhorar a precisão nos números finais?

Answer (score 0):

Não vejo o motivo para a precisão estar incorreta, a única coisa errada me parece a falta de um **"t"** em **sqrt**

Testei o código abaixo e funcionou perfeitamente.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

main() {
    double dist;
    int x1 = 10, x2 = 20, y1 = 30, y2= 50;

    dist = sqrt(pow(x2 - x1, 2) + pow(y2 - y1, 2));
            printf("%.2lf", dist);
    return 0;
}
```

A saída é

> 22.36

Pode ver o teste online [aqui.](http://ideone.com/X1DOIj)

Comment: Caso não resolva, poste seu código completo para que possa analisar melhor.